# symfony/silex csr.token_manager not defined

Tags: symfony, silex

i have a project in silex that works perfectly on my Windows running xampp, but when i cloned it to my Ubuntu it threw the error  
**"InvalidArgumentException in Container.php line 96:
Identifier "csrf.token_manager" is not defined."**
I'm not using xampp or lamp on Ubuntu so i guess it could be some configuration of the apache2 or php.
I had an error before with csrf_provider and solved it with

```
$app['form.csrf_provider'] = null;
```

but if i try do do something like that it says it espects CsrfProviderInterface or CsrfTokenManagerInterface or null, or it just ignores if i'm logged in or not.
 I tried to find something around but i just found how to handle the token manager manually, i just want it to work as is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you forget to run ```composer install``` on your cloned copy? It seems you're missing some dependencies... if not, which version of Symfony/security are you requireing in your composer (or Silex's one)?

Comment: my composer says everything it's updated, i'm using symfony/security 2.6 and symfony/security-csrf 2.6 in silex 2.0

Comment: Have you tried to specifically register the [CsrfTokenProvider](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/doc/providers/csrf.rst)? If that does not work, I would reinstall all dependencies by deleting the vendor folder and running a ```composer install``` again (or update if you've passed the composer.json file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mTorres i solved it registering the CsrfTokenProvider

```
use Silex\Provider\CsrfServiceProvider;
$app->register(new CsrfServiceProvider());
```

No idea why it works on windows whitout it though.